# whenever i run my fragment this line of code mapFragment.setRetainInstance(true); is crashing my app?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-maps, android-fragments, android-viewpager

So i had a maps activity that i changed to a fragment so I can display It on my viewpager but after changing the Activity to a fragment this line of code mapFragment.setRetainInstance(true); is crashing the app. Did i miss anything when changing the MapsActivity to a Fragment, ill put the old MapsActivity class and the one i changed to fragment below so you guys can take a look at.

MapsActivity.java that i changed to a fragment so i can display it on viewpager:

```
 public class MapsActivity extends Fragment
      implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener, 
 com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener {
View view;
Context context;
public static boolean SAVE_LOCATION,SAVE_LOCATION_ADDRESS;
private static final String TAG = "Current Location";
  GoogleMap mGoogleMap;
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
Location mLastLocation;
private LatLng mDefaultLocation;
private static final int DEFAULT_ZOOM = 15;
private static final int PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION = 1;
private static final int PERMISSION_DATA_ACCESS_CODE = 2;
private boolean mLocationPermissionGranted;
String lat,long_;
SwitchCompat current_loction_switch,selected_location_switch;
ExpandableRelativeLayout expandable_layout;
TextView my_current_location;
TextView new_location_txt;
boolean isMaptouched=false;
private GeoDataClient mGeoDataClient;
private PlaceDetectionClient mPlaceDetectionClient;
// The entry point to the Fused Location Provider.
private FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationProviderClient;
// A default location (Sydney, Australia) and default zoom to use when location permission is
// not granted.
private Location mLastKnownLocation;
private SupportMapFragment mapFragment;
private MapView mapView;
private SharedPreferences sPredMap;
private GoogleMap.OnCameraIdleListener onCameraIdleListener;
ImageView close_country;
TextView current_text_tv;
RelativeLayout current_address_div;
       Button save_loc_div;
ImageButton arrow_down;

public MapsActivity() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    context = getContext();
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main_maps, container, false);
   SharedPreferences sPredMap = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences(Variables.pref_name,MODE_PRIVATE);
    lat = sPredMap.getString(Variables.seleted_Lat,"");
    long_ = sPredMap.getString(Variables.selected_Lon,"");
    if(lat.isEmpty()&&long_.isEmpty()){
        lat =  sPredMap.getString(Variables.current_Lat,"");
        long_ =sPredMap.getString(Variables.current_Lon,"");
    }


    mDefaultLocation = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(lat), Double.parseDouble(long_));     
    current_text_tv = view.findViewById(R.id.current_text_tv);
    close_country = view.findViewById(R.id.close_country);
    current_address_div = view.findViewById(R.id.current_address_div);
    save_loc_div = view.findViewById(R.id.save_loc_div);


    save_loc_div.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            SAVE_LOCATION = true;
            SAVE_LOCATION_ADDRESS = true;
            Intent data = new Intent();
            data.putExtra("lat", String.valueOf(lat));
            data.putExtra("lng", String.valueOf(long_));
            data.putExtra("location_string",current_text_tv.getText());
            getActivity().setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, data);
            //(RESULT_OK, data);
            String latSearch = data.getStringExtra("lat");
            String longSearch = data.getStringExtra("lng");
            String location_string = data.getStringExtra("location_string");
            new_location_txt.setText(location_string);
            new_location_txt.setText(location_string);
            selected_location_switch.setClickable(true);
            current_loction_switch.setClickable(true);
            selected_location_switch.setChecked(true);

            MainMenuActivity.sharedPreferences.edit().putString(Variables.seleted_Lat,latSearch).commit();
            MainMenuActivity.sharedPreferences.edit().putString(Variables.selected_Lon,longSearch).commit();

            MainMenuActivity.sharedPreferences.edit().putString(Variables.selected_location_string,location_string).commit();


        }
    });

    current_address_div.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), SearchPlaces.class);
            startActivityForResult(i, PERMISSION_DATA_ACCESS_CODE);

        }
    });
    close_country.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            getActivity().finish();
        }
    });

     mGeoDataClient = Places.getGeoDataClient(this.getActivity(), null);

    // Construct a PlaceDetectionClient.
    mPlaceDetectionClient = Places.getPlaceDetectionClient(this.getActivity(), null);

    // Construct a FusedLocationProviderClient.
    mFusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this.getActivity());


    setupMapIfNeeded();

    configureCameraIdle();

    mapFragment.setRetainInstance(true);

    current_loction_switch = view.findViewById(R.id.current_loction_switch);
    selected_location_switch=view.findViewById(R.id.selected_location_switch);

    if(MainMenuActivity.sharedPreferences.getBoolean(Variables.is_seleted_location_selected,false)){
        selected_location_switch.setChecked(true);
    }else {
        current_loction_switch.setChecked(true);
    }



    current_loction_switch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

            Variables.is_reload_users=true;

            if(isChecked){
                MainMenuActivity.sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean(Variables.is_seleted_location_selected,false).commit();
                selected_location_switch.setChecked(false);
             
            }else {

                MainMenuActivity.sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean(Variables.is_seleted_location_selected,true).commit();
                selected_location_switch.setChecked(true);
                // my_current_location.setText(MainMenuActivity.sharedPreferences.getString(Variables.selected_location_string,""));
            }

        }
    });



    selected_location_switch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

            Variables.is_reload_users=true;

            if(isChecked){
                MainMenuActivity.sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean(Variables.is_seleted_location_selected,true).commit();
                current_loction_switch.setChecked(false);
                my_current_location.setText(MainMenuActivity.sharedPreferences.getString(Variables.selected_location_string,""));
            }else {
                MainMenuActivity.sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean(Variables.is_seleted_location_selected,false).commit();
                current_loction_switch.setChecked(true);
           
            }


        }
    });

    new_location_txt=view.findViewById(R.id.new_location_txt);


    if(!MainMenuActivity.sharedPreferences.getString(Variables.selected_location_string,"").equals("")){
        new_location_txt.setText(MainMenuActivity.sharedPreferences.getString(Variables.selected_location_string,""));
    }else {
        selected_location_switch.setClickable(false);
        current_loction_switch.setClickable(false);
    }

    //below code is to collapse expanble view when arrow is clicked

    expandable_layout=view.findViewById(R.id.expandable_layout);
    arrow_down =view.findViewById(R.id.arrow_down);
    arrow_down.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){

            if(expandable_layout.isExpanded()){
                arrow_down.setRotation(90);
                expandable_layout.collapse();


            }
            else
                arrow_down.setRotation(270);
                expandable_layout.expand();


        }
    });
    return view;

}



@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();

    setupMapIfNeeded();

}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

}
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mGoogleMap = googleMap;
    updateLocationUI();
    getDeviceLocation();

    mGoogleMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(false);
    MapStateManager mgr = new MapStateManager(this.getActivity());
    CameraPosition position = mgr.getSavedCameraPosition();
    if (position != null) {
        CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(position);
        mGoogleMap.moveCamera(update);

        mGoogleMap.setMapType(mgr.getSavedMapType());
    }

    if (mGoogleMap != null) {
        mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("Marker"));
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext()
                , Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext()
                , Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
          
            return;
        }
        mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        mGoogleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);

    }
    mGoogleMap.setOnCameraIdleListener(onCameraIdleListener);
}


@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
}
private void updateLocationUI() {
    if (mGoogleMap == null) {
        return;
    }
    try {
        if (mLocationPermissionGranted) {
            mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            mGoogleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
        } else {
            mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(false);
             mGoogleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
            mLastKnownLocation = null;
            getLocationPermission();
        }
    } catch (SecurityException e)  {
        Log.e("Exception: %s", e.getMessage());
    }
}
private void getDeviceLocation() {

    try {
        if (mLocationPermissionGranted) {
            Task locationResult = mFusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation();
            locationResult.addOnCompleteListener(this.getActivity(), new OnCompleteListener() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        // Set the map's camera position to the current location of the device.
                        mLastKnownLocation = (Location) task.getResult();
                        mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                                new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(lat), Double.parseDouble(long_)), DEFAULT_ZOOM));
                        mGoogleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);

                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sPredMap.edit();
                        editor.putString(Variables.current_Lat, String.valueOf(lat));
                        editor.putString(Variables.current_Lon, String.valueOf(long_));
                        editor.apply();

                    } else {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Current location is null. Using defaults.");
                        Log.e(TAG, "Exception: %s", task.getException());
                        mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(mDefaultLocation, DEFAULT_ZOOM));
                        mGoogleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
                         }
                }
            });
        }
    } catch(SecurityException e)  {
        Log.e("Exception: %s", e.getMessage());
    }

   }
private void configureCameraIdle() {
    onCameraIdleListener = new GoogleMap.OnCameraIdleListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCameraIdle() {

            LatLng latLng = mGoogleMap.getCameraPosition().target;
            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getActivity(), Locale.getDefault());

            try {
                List<Address> addressList = geocoder.getFromLocation(latLng.latitude, latLng.longitude, 1);
                if (addressList != null && addressList.size() > 0) {
                   
                    String country = addressList.get(0).getCountryName();
                   
                        lat = ""+latLng.latitude;
                        long_ = ""+latLng.longitude;
                     
                        current_text_tv.setText(country);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
}
private void setupMapIfNeeded(){
    // Build the map.
    if(mGoogleMap==null) {
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    }
}
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    MapStateManager mgr = new MapStateManager(this.getActivity());
    mgr.saveMapState(mGoogleMap);

}


private void getLocationPermission() {
/*
 * Request location permission, so that we can get the location of the
 * device. The result of the permission request is handled by a callback,
 * onRequestPermissionsResult.
 */
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
            android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        mLocationPermissionGranted = true;
    } else {
        try {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(),
                    new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.getMessage();
        }

    }
}
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == PERMISSION_DATA_ACCESS_CODE) {
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            String latSearch = data.getStringExtra("lat");
            String longSearch = data.getStringExtra("lng");
            lat = latSearch;
            long_ = longSearch;
            mDefaultLocation = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(latSearch), Double.parseDouble(longSearch));
            mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(mDefaultLocation, DEFAULT_ZOOM));
        }
    }

    if (requestCode == 111) {
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            String latSearch = data.getStringExtra("lat");
            String longSearch = data.getStringExtra("lng");
            String location_string = data.getStringExtra("location_string");
            new_location_txt.setText(location_string);
            new_location_txt.setText(location_string);
            selected_location_switch.setClickable(true);
            current_loction_switch.setClickable(true);
            selected_location_switch.setChecked(true);

            MainMenuActivity.sharedPreferences.edit().putString(Variables.seleted_Lat,latSearch).commit();
            MainMenuActivity.sharedPreferences.edit().putString(Variables.selected_Lon,longSearch).commit();

            MainMenuActivity.sharedPreferences.edit().putString(Variables.selected_location_string,location_string).commit();

        }
    }
}
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       @NonNull String permissions[],
                                       @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    mLocationPermissionGranted = false;
    switch (requestCode) {
        case PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION: {
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                mLocationPermissionGranted = true;
                updateLocationUI();
            }
        }
    }

}
protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this.getActivity())
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API).build();

    if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }
}
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    mLastLocation = location;
      }
@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {
}
@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {
}
@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {
}
@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(0);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(0);
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
}
@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
}
private void getDriversAround(){
    DatabaseReference driversLocation = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(("availableUsers"));
 }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mapFragment` is `null`. Kindly verify that your `layout` file contains

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

And you are inflating the correct `layout` file. Secondly, your function `setupMapIfNeeded` is having wrong condition. Your condition should be on fragment and it must be assigned to global variable `mapFragment`

**setupMapIfNeeded**

```
private void setupMapIfNeeded(){
    // Build the map.
    if(mapFragment==null) {
        mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    }
}
```